# Mongo convert embedded document to array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to convert a nested document structure into an array? Below is an example:

**Input**

```
"experience" : {
        "0" : {
            "duration" : "3 months",
            "end" : "August 2012",
            "organization" : {
                "0" : {
                    "name" : "Bank of China",
                    "profile_url" : "http://www.linkedin.com/company/13801"
                }
            },
            "start" : "June 2012",
            "title" : "Intern Analyst"
        }
    },
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"experience" : [
           {
            "duration" : "3 months",
            "end" : "August 2012",
            "organization" : {
                "0" : {
                    "name" : "Bank of China",
                    "profile_url" : "http://www.linkedin.com/company/13801"
                }
            },
            "start" : "June 2012",
            "title" : "Intern Analyst"
        }
    ],
```

Currently I am using a script to iterate over each element, convert them to an array & finally update the document. But it is taking a lot of time, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please mention your mongodb version? Also mention if you want to transform your document permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to iterate over the content, but instead you should be writing back using bulk operations:

Either for MongoDB 2.6 and greater:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.find({ 
   "$where": "return !Array.isArray(this.experience)"
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "experience": [doc.experience["0"]] }
    });
    count++;

    // Write once in 1000 entries
    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();    
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Write the remaining
if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Or in modern releases of MongoDB 3.2 and greater, the [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method is preferred:

```js
var ops = [];

db.collection.find({ 
   "$where": "return !Array.isArray(this.experience)"
}).forEach(function(doc) {
   ops.push({
       "updateOne": {
           "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
           "update": { "$set": { "experience": [doc.experience["0"]] } }
       }
   });

   if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
       db.collection.bulkWrite(ops,{ "ordered": false })
       ops = [];
   }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 )
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops,{ "ordered": false });
```

So when writing back to the database over a cursor, then bulk write operations with "unordered" set is the way to go. It's only one write/response per batch of 1000 requests, which reduces a lot of overhead, and "unordered" means that writes can happen in parallel rather than in a serial order. It all makes it faster.

Answer (score 1):

**For mongoDB version >4.2 :**

```
db.doc.aggregate([{ $match: {'experience.0': { $exists: false } } },
    {$project:{experience:["$experience.0"]}}, { $merge: { into: "doc", on: "_id" }
])
```

**Note :** Here we're merging the updated field/document with existing, but not replacing/updating entire document, default behavior of `$merge` is `merge` **whenMatched** document is found, You can pass other options like replace/keepExisting etc.

**Ref:** [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html)

Comment: This answer is based on @Saleem's answer, as my edit on his answer to include these new changes(features in mongoDB) was rejected & suggestion is to make this as a new answer !!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, why aren't there any good answers **yet**.

It's super easy with aggregation "$set", set is used to add a new field. here you can add a new field with same name into an array. So it will override the older field.

Refer below example:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate[
   // match/other aggregations
   {$set: { "experience": ["$experience"] } }
];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Dead simple yet effective.

Answer (score 0):

See if this query works with your MongoDB version

For MongoDB version 3.2+:

```
db.doc.aggregate([
    {$project:{experience:["$experience.0"]}}
])
```

MongoDB < 3.2:

```
db.doc.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:"$_id", experience:{$push:"$experience.0"}}}
])
```

It should transform your document into:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f1b046a65ea8a72c34839c"), 
    "experience" : [
        {
            "duration" : "3 months", 
            "end" : "August 2012", 
            "organization" : {
                "0" : {
                    "name" : "Bank of China", 
                    "profile_url" : "http://www.linkedin.com/company/13801"
                }
            }, 
            "start" : "June 2012", 
            "title" : "Intern Analyst"
        }
    ]
}
```

A better approach if you want to alter documents in collection permanently using aggregation framework.

Lets assume your collection name is `doc`

```
db.doc.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:"$_id", experience:{$push:"$experience.0"}}},
    {$out: "doc"}
])
```

Query above will transform all of your documents in place.

Comment: It's still an incorrect approach regardless of the version. You keep repeating the same thing over and over without understanding what is wrong with it.