# How to force an array in Talend tMongoDBOutput component

Tags: json, mongodb, talend

You can see here that when I have a single "location" I don't get an array, and this is causing me some issues.  I am trying to create a nested document from a one-to-many relationship in Oracle.

How can I force an array, I have tried creating an @class attribute of array to force it in the JSON Tree, but that just doesn't work.

[image]

My set up is below:

[image]

Group By is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Again, tWriteJSONField converts to XML before JSON, therefore the node context is not recognized as an array by json-lib.

You can split the header and detail using tMap, write the locations into a temporary file using a tFileOutputJSON with "Generated an array json" checked. Finally your merge the header and detail (put a dummy tag in the header / country then use String.replace to inject the locations into the header).

Here is an example: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5c9497e91a4f121aace0cf1cba92367b20170219131432/d275cc

You can also look for a better component on https://exchange.talend.com (tJSONDoc* looks like a good candidate), or write some custom code using tJavaFlex.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I ended up doing post processing in a tMongoRow using this logic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164746/mongo-convert-embedded-document-to-array

Comment: Will definitely take a look at tJSONDoc